# Clearing borders on merged cells

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to clear borders, on merged cells. This cause a error:
[image]

This code line:

```
battle.Range("o11:o12").Clear
```

I tried another .clear suboptions, but no works. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
battle.Range("o11:o12").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
```